# Unable to save a view in a different BigQuery project

Tags: google-bigquery

I have my big query table ***Tab1*** in GCP Project A. I have created a new GCP Project B. I have written a query that retrieves data stored in ***Tab1*** and I want to store this as view in Project B.

I am getting an error like this:

*Not found: Dataset Project A:Tab1 not found*

Both projects are under the same organization. How do I create views in new projects based on data stored in another project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to query a table that is not located in the project that you are using, you have to also specified the project_name in the `FROM`.

For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM `project_A.dataset.tab1`
```

Based on the error message, you are not doing that properly (`` `project_ID.dataset.table` ``)

Comment: No I am doing all this right. The query runs and the view can be saved under Project A. The error gets thrown when I try to save under Project B.

Comment: Can you add the queries and how you are doing it?

Comment: The query is like: SELECT * FROM `Project-A.dataset.tab1`

And I am trying to save it as a view under Project-B.dataset1.view1`

Comment: I can do it. It might be that you don't have enough permissions in the projects. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

If the rights are good, you can do as Alvaro said, othewise if it didnt works, you can add/declare some rights for your view as  :

One possibility is to create an authorized view  in the dataset permission ,
[image]

And after that you can add your view :

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. It doesn't let me authorize a dataset in another project.

Comment: Can you go to the IAM and add yourself to the project A and B with the rights Biquery Admin ?

Close all your windows and retry to create the view in your project after

RQ : Think to check the localisation of your dataset in your different project , if you has a dataset in EU for example you cannot query from an US dataset.